# PGP Signing with BouncyCastle java API and verifying using gpg4win is not working

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle APIs to sign a file. I am using bcpg-jdk15on-164.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-164.jar and bcprov-ext-jdk15on-164.jar.

I am following their example to sign a text file. After signing the file, when I changed the content in the text file and tried to verify using Gpg4Win, I still see that the signature is valid but there is no indication that the file couldn't be verified.

I created two signatures for the same text file. One with the code below producing .asc file and the other with Gpg4Win producing .sig file. I then modified the text file. I double clicked each of the signatures where I expect the signature to become invalid because of the file being changed after the signature was generated. However, signature generated by BouncyCastle  still does not indicate that the file has been changed as shown in the image. BouncyCastle signature shows up as green while the signature generated by Gpg4Win shows up as red. 
Image: [Verifying BouncyCastle signature vs GPG4Win signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDpBG.png)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPOnePassSignature;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPOnePassSignatureList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignature;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.KeyFingerPrintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPContentVerifierBuilderProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder;

/**
 * A simple utility class that signs and verifies files.
 * <p>
 * To sign a file: SignedFileProcessor -s [-a] fileName secretKey passPhrase.<br>
 * If -a is specified the output file will be "ascii-armored".
 * <p>
 * To decrypt: SignedFileProcessor -v fileName publicKeyFile.
 * <p>
 * <b>Note</b>: this example will silently overwrite files, nor does it pay any attention to
 * the specification of "_CONSOLE" in the filename. It also expects that a single pass phrase
 * will have been used.
 * <p>
 * <b>Note</b>: the example also makes use of PGP compression. If you are having difficulty getting it
 * to interoperate with other PGP programs try removing the use of compression first.
 */
public class SignedFileProcessor
{

    /**
     * Generate an encapsulated signed file.
     * 
     * @param fileName
     * @param keyIn
     * @param out
     * @param pass
     * @param armor
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     * @throws PGPException
     * @throws SignatureException
     */
    private static void signFile(
        String          fileName,
        InputStream     keyIn,
        OutputStream    out,
        char[]          pass,
        boolean         armor)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, PGPException, SignatureException
    {
        if (armor)
        {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        PGPSecretKey                pgpSec = readSecretKey(keyIn);
        PGPPrivateKey               pgpPrivKey = pgpSec.extractPrivateKey(new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(pass));
        PGPSignatureGenerator       sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(pgpSec.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1).setProvider("BC"));

        sGen.init(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, pgpPrivKey);

        Iterator    it = pgpSec.getPublicKey().getUserIDs();
        if (it.hasNext())
        {
            PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator  spGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();

            spGen.setSignerUserID(false, (String)it.next());
            sGen.setHashedSubpackets(spGen.generate());
        }

        PGPCompressedDataGenerator  cGen = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZLIB);

        BCPGOutputStream            bOut = new BCPGOutputStream(cGen.open(out));

        sGen.generateOnePassVersion(false).encode(bOut);

        File                        file = new File(fileName);
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator     lGen = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream                lOut = lGen.open(bOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, file);
        FileInputStream             fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        int                         ch;

        while ((ch = fIn.read()) >= 0)
        {
            lOut.write(ch);
            sGen.update((byte)ch);
        }

        lGen.close();

        sGen.generate().encode(bOut);

        cGen.close();

        if (armor)
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(
        String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String rootFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
        String fileName = rootFolder + "\\files\\helloworld.txt";
        FileInputStream     keyIn = new FileInputStream(rootFolder + "\\files\\sign-and-encrypt_priv.asc");
        FileOutputStream    out = new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".asc");


        signFile(fileName, keyIn, out, "hongkong".toCharArray(), true);
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    /**
     * A simple routine that opens a key ring file and loads the first available key
     * suitable for signature generation.
     * 
     * @param input stream to read the secret key ring collection from.
     * @return a secret key.
     * @throws IOException on a problem with using the input stream.
     * @throws PGPException if there is an issue parsing the input stream.
     */
    static PGPSecretKey readSecretKey(InputStream input) throws IOException, PGPException
    {
        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(
            PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(input), new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());

        //
        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real
        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
        //

        Iterator keyRingIter = pgpSec.getKeyRings();
        while (keyRingIter.hasNext())
        {
            PGPSecretKeyRing keyRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing)keyRingIter.next();

            Iterator keyIter = keyRing.getSecretKeys();
            while (keyIter.hasNext())
            {
                PGPSecretKey key = (PGPSecretKey)keyIter.next();

                if (key.isSigningKey())
                {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find signing key in key ring.");
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Is the signature generated by BouncyCastle with the code above valid at all to ensure the integrity of the file and its signature? I have tried previous version (version 150) of BouncyCastle, I also tried not using BCPGOutputStream stream, but that did not help either.

Comment: You need to explain what the image you posted is showing.

Comment: I have updated my question adding more details. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the signFile as below created a detached signature, which worked with Gpg4Win as expected:

```
private static void signFile(
        String          fileName,
        InputStream     keyIn,
        OutputStream    out,
        char[]          pass,
        boolean         armor)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, PGPException, SignatureException
    {
        if (armor)
        {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        PGPSecretKey             pgpSec = readSecretKey(keyIn);
        PGPPrivateKey            pgpPrivKey = pgpSec.extractPrivateKey(new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(pass));
        PGPSignatureGenerator    sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(pgpSec.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1).setProvider("BC"));

        sGen.init(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, pgpPrivKey);

        BCPGOutputStream         bOut = new BCPGOutputStream(out);

        InputStream              fIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

        int ch;
        while ((ch = fIn.read()) >= 0)
        {
            sGen.update((byte)ch);
        }

        fIn.close();

        sGen.generate().encode(bOut);

        if (armor)
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```